# Is there a PHP linter that can restrict class imports based on custom boundary rules?

Tags: php, dependencies, lint, coupling, cohesion

We have a monorepo that includes our old monolith as well as our new modules. (We don't want separate repos...yet)

```
src/Monolith/...
src/OrderModule/...
src/PaymentModule/...
```

We obviously don't want our new modules coupled to the monolith. We also don't want certain modules depending on other modules. eg: the `OrderModule` can depend on the `PaymentModule`, but not the other way around.

**Is there a phpcs or linter rule for preventing "innapropriate" cohesion?** Something that restricts imports would work.

JavaScript's ESLint has `no-restricted-imports`, `no-restricted-modules` and `nx-enforce-module-boundaries` which will enforce custom boundary rules. Is there a PHP equivalent?

*Bonus:* We're using DDD hexagonal architecture, so we could even use these rules to enforce separation between the application, domain and infrastructure layers!